# Page builder and Sticky popup plugin both are not working together - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, conflict

In my wordpress site I am using both page builder and sticky popup plugin. When  both plugins are activated in a page it conflicts. But I need both these plugins together. Any Solution?

Comment: C'mon Natasha, help us to help you, way to little info ;-). What are the conflicts?? Do you see errors in the console log? Can't u use another popup plugin like [popupmaker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/)?

Comment: give us the URL at least where they conflict and stop working please.

Comment: If include both plugins in a page..sticky popup shows the pagebuilder content not showing popup form